# Nginx config reload without downtime

Tags: nginx

I use nginx as a reverse proxy.
Whenever I update the config for it using

```
sudo "cp -r #{nginx_config_path}* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/"
sudo "kill -s HUP `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`"
```

I face a brief downtime. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Are those meant to be command line commands? I've never seen anyone wrap an entire sudo command in quotes like that, it may not be necessary.

Comment: Just a general comment: I think the standard/recommended practice is create a soft/symbolic link for your site configuration under `sites-enabled`, not copy it. Not related to your particular issue, but you may want to look into that.

Comment: You should not be facing a downtime. `kill HUP` is the way to do a graceful reload in nginx.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Run `service nginx reload`, `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` or `/usr/sbin/nginx reload`

It will do a hot reload of the configuration without downtime. If you have pending requests, then there will be lingering nginx processes that will handle those connections before it dies, so it's an extremely graceful way to reload configs.

Sometimes you may want to prepend with `sudo`

Comment: Both of those should do exactly what the question states: send `SIGHUP` to the nginx master process. There should not be a difference. http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Comment: When I issue the command on CentOS it keeps saying "Usage /etc/init.d/nginx (start..stop...restart..reload)" .. and that's exactly how I used it. Within the file /init.d/nginx I found kill -HUP `cat $PIDFILE` || echo -n " can't reload"

Comment: do you know what the difference is between `service nginx reload` and `nginx -s reload`? If I run the former, I get this output: `Reloading nginx configuration: nginx.`, but my changes aren't updated. If I run the latter, I get no output, but my changes are reflected.

Comment: I just tried this after adding a `log_not_found` directive but found that I had to actually do a restart to get it to work. I guess reloading does not work for all directives?

Comment: I get downtime when I do this. For example I get blips like 502 bad gateway which is killing some requests. I'm running an old version of nginx - not sure if that's the reason

Comment: sorry not bad gateway but Error socket hang up

Comment: This is not an option when nginx is running in a container.

Comment: This doesn't really answer op's question though, does it? Reload still causes downtime, and kills the site processes even if they're not effected by the site config. It does it more gracefully than a full restart, but it still causes downtime, which op doesn't want.

Comment: Worth pointing out that on RedHat 7 and CentOS 7 the command changed to `systemctl reload nginx`

Answer (score 148):

Run `/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload`

See http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine for more command line options.

Comment: Finally, a command that does work in Debian Jessie.

Comment: This is a better way. Because your server doesn't *down* if your configurations have errors (just shows errors in this case).

Comment: if nginx default pid not in  the default  location , need '-p'. ie:  ` /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -s reload -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx`

Answer (score 15):

### Nginx and Signals

The `kill` approach you used (`kill -s HUP $(cat /var/run/nginx.pid`) is correct. Init scripts for RH or Debian distributions are in the end also implemented using `kill` command. You can check [Init example from nginx website](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/redhatnginxinit/) or contents of [Ubuntu Nginx package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nginx).

There are multiple signals, that nginx can listen to ([mentioned in wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/#stopping-or-restarting-nginx)):

- `TERM`, `INT` - Quick shutdown.
- `QUIT` - Graceful shutdown.
- `KILL` - Halts a stubborn process.
- `HUP` - Configuration reload. Start the new worker processes with a new configuration. Gracefully shutdown the old worker processes.
- `USR1` - Reopen the log files.
- `USR2` - Upgrade Executable on the fly.
- `WINCH` - Gracefully shutdown the worker processes.

### Nginx Reload

Nginx reload (`HUP` signal) is more specifically implemented as several steps [1,2]:

- The master process checks the syntax validity.
- Applies new configuration, that is, to open log files and new listen sockets.
- If this fails, it rolls back changes and continues to work with old configuration.
- If this succeeds, it starts new worker processes, and sends messages to old worker processes requesting them to shut down gracefully.
- Old worker processes close listen sockets and continue to service old clients.
- After all clients are serviced, old worker processes are shut down.

Only one issue I can think of why you had downtime (based on the reload process) is that you were using only one worker process (`worker_processes` directive), which by design was serving old clients, but had closed listen socket, therefore you couldn't open new connection.

I can also recommend you to always use `/usr/sbin/nginx -t` to validate configuration files before applying new config.

### Nginx Reload in Depth

[Reconfigure signal is handled in file `ngx_process_cycle.c`](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/4bf4650f2f10f7bbacfe7a33da744f18951d416d/src/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L221) and we can see it starts new worker processes in function `ngx_start_worker_processes(...)` and at the end it stops old worker processes in function `ngx_signal_worker_processes(...)`, which [iterates over them](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/4bf4650f2f10f7bbacfe7a33da744f18951d416d/src/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L493) with `NGX_SHUTDOWN_SIGNAL` signal.

Resources:

- [1] https://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html
- [2] https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/#stopping-or-restarting-nginx

Comment: So that means that "nginx -s reload" does not restart the nginx service (i.e. resulting in a new pid) but just instructs the nginx service to reload its configuration without a restart? If I have a docker container in which I am attached to the nginx process with "nginx -g 'daemon off;' " making a reload would not kill my container then?

Comment: @Crine No, it will not kill your container.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm doing this and it doesn't seem to be picking up changes made to the `nginx.conf` file. I've added a few `location` blocks to test and indeed hitting localhost/test didn't exist even after sending the nanny process a HUP (and verifying new worker process pids). Is there any insight available into the steps you outlined here (ie, applies new config, rolls back, etc)? Interested in debugging this.

Comment: @ap can you confirm that the configuration file you use is actually working and the issue is only in reload process?

Answer (score 12):

No, you are incorrect, you aren't supposed to be facing any downtime with the procedure you describe.  (Nginx can do not only configuration reload on the fly without any downtime, but even the upgrade of the executable on the fly, still without any downtime.)

As per http://nginx.org/docs/control.html#reconfiguration, sending the `HUP` signal to nginx makes sure that it performs a graceful restart, and, if the configuration files are incorrect, the whole procedure is abandoned, and you're left with the nginx as before sending the `HUP` signal.  At no point should any downtime be possible.

> In order for nginx to re-read the configuration file, a HUP signal should be sent to the master process. The master process first checks the syntax validity, then tries to apply new configuration, that is, to open log files and new listen sockets. If this fails, it rolls back changes and continues to work with old configuration.

Answer (score 12):

For completeness, the `systemd` way of doing it:

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, reloading configuration file of a service should not affect the running service. However, this depends on how the `SIGHUP` signal is processed.

If a specific service is experiencing a downtime during reload, this can be circumvented by running the same service on multiple servers preferably using a load balancer. In this case, you can take out one server at a time and reload/restart it. Then, it can be re-added after confirming it is OK.

Comment: While this does not directly answer the question, this is definitely a best-practice scenario that the OP would be smart to follow for avoiding downtime in general.

Comment: Details on how nginx handles different signals: http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Answer (score 0):

First, you sure true the config. You should check the config in nginx.conf. You can use command below for the check.

```
nginx -t
```

After that, if config is true, you can nginx reload. False is first of all must edit your config and than again check use `nginx -t` and nginx reload.

You can use the below command.

```
systemctl reload nginx
```